# Creating a tooltip in Flex

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, flex3, tooltip

I am trying to have a tool-tip in Flex 3, where in when my mouse is over the some value, it should show a tool-tip just like you get it for any classes in `Eclipse IDE.`

Suppose, your mouse is over word "`String`" in java, you get a tool-tip stating the description of `java.lang.String` and its syntax. It also allows to copy the contents.

Is it possible to create such a tool-tip in **Flex 3** ? Can anyone please help me ?

Thanks.

---

**Edit :** I want this kind of tool-tip to appear, and when pressed F2, it should have horizontal and vertical scroll bars and we should be able to copy the contents from tool-tip.

[image]

Comment: where do you want the tooltip? In your Flex application or the Flex code?

Comment: I want the tool-tip to appear once I hover on some value in my flex application running on web browser...

Comment: Ok, my answer below should help then!

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know should be in [these docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f3f.html).

---

[The Flex 3 version of the same docs.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/tooltips_1.html)

Comment: That's a flex 4.5 doc link, while he needs Flex 3 :)

Comment: My bad; I added the Flex 3 link.

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't have what I need ... Please read the question again

Comment: Read the information on creating custom tooltips: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/tooltips_4.html#149007 .  That is exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an Eclipse like experience during Flex 3 development, you need the [FlashBuilder IDE](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html).

If it's over a UI control (text, button, field, etc.) in your running Flex application, you need to use the `toolTip` attribute (see http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=tooltips_3.html for samples).

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't have what I need ... Please read the question again

Comment: perhaps, you can wrap the text in a label and add the 'toolTip' to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to create a custom component, and write `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` handlers for the component that is supposed to trigger the "toolTip".

**Edit**

You'll have to also add code to check that when the mouse leaves the trigger, if it is on the toolTip, then the toolTip must not close.

Sorry about the instructions without code, I'll try to write you a demo when I get home